# How can I create a center disk to put under a compass point?

Tags: tool-usage, material-making

I want to get my hands on one of these disks used to rest the sharp point of a compass on so it will not make a hole in the paper. Someone suggested this device in another question, but I can't find one anywhere online.
Is it possible to make one myself, or is there something I can use to act as one of these tools?

Comment: Hi Marcia, welcome to Arts & Crafts. I had initially closed your question as off-topic (asking where to find products is off-topic as pointed out in our [Help section](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), but since it already had an answer that deals with your needs within the parameters of this platform, and it is more helpful to slightly edit your question than to close it, I decided to do so. I hope you get what you want out of this :)

Answer (score 2):

For something of this sort, you'll either construct one yourself, or repurpose a common item from another resource. The first thought that popped into my alleged mind is a coaster, something with a reasonably solid bottom layer to prevent puncture and also to provide grip, and an upper layer with material suitable to hold the compass point.

Even a sheet of hobby plywood cut in a shape to meet your needs should work. You'd be able to cut more than one, to have replacements when the point holes are excessive in quantity.

Shelf liner and drawer liner made of an open mesh material that's spongy is found in grocery and big-box stores and can be applied to the bottom of the coaster or coaster substitute to prevent slipping.